# Why did part of my mesh suddenly turn purple in sculp mode? (Face sets)

Tags: sculpting

I was just sculpting a rock object in object mode, when all of a sudden, parts of it just turned purple.  I don't think I pressed anything I shouldn't have.  I don't know if this is normal of not, but does anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Sculpt* mode, *Face Sets* allows you to create separate areas, a little bit like the *Mask* except you can create as many face sets as you want and you won't have to mask and unmask to switch from a face set to another, when you'll sculpt on a face set it will only affect this face set until you release the left click and click on another face set.

To paint your face sets you need to press left click. Release and left click again to create a new face set, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left click on a face set to extend it, <kbd>Shift</kbd> left click to smooth the boundaries. In the *Face Sets* menu > *Init Face Sets* you can choose another way to create face sets (for example *By UV Seams*):

[image]

Once you've painted, choose your sculpt brush and enable the *Face Sets* options:

[image]

It looks like once you've painted your face sets you can't enable *Dyntopo* without deleting the face sets, *Dyntopo* creates new geometry so it makes sense.

Now sculpt:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

never mind, I figured it out.  I had accidantally enabled "face sets"  whatever that is.  But anyway, I got it back to normal now

Answer (score 1):

#### How To Remove Face Sets

To remove/reset all `Face Sets`, you can navigate to the top left corner of your viewport and click the `Face Sets` button.

From here, click `Face Set From Visible` to reset the entire mesh back to the default grey.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can go to the top left corner and click on `Viewport Overlays`. Then at the very bottom, toggle off `Face Set` visibility.